# Unable to call intent

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I try to call this activity from other activity, however, the apps forced quit.
This is my code.

```
public class Records extends Activity {

// Array of strings storing country names
String[] types = new String[] {
    "Tutorial Room",
    "Lecture Hall",
    "Tutorial Room",
    "Tutorial Room"
};

// Array of integers points to images stored in /res/drawable-ldpi/
int[] icon = new int[]{
    R.drawable.tutorialroom,
    R.drawable.lecturehall,
    R.drawable.tutorialroom,
    R.drawable.tutorialroom
};

// Array of strings to store currencies
String[] info = new String[]{
    "Booking1",
    "Booking2",
    "Booking3",
    "Booking4"
};

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Each row in the list stores country name, currency and flag
    List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
        hm.put("txt", "Name : " + types[i]);
        hm.put("cur","Type : " + info[i]);
        hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(icon[i]) );
        aList.add(hm);
    }

    // Keys used in Hashmap
    String[] from = { "flag","txt","cur" };

    // Ids of views in listview_layout
    int[] to = { R.id.flag,R.id.txt,R.id.cur};

    // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
    // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);

    // Getting a reference to listview of main.xml layout file
    ListView listView = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    // Setting the adapter to the listView
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

> 08-23 12:19:50.449: E/AndroidRuntime(7642): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   08-23 12:19:50.449: E/AndroidRuntime(7642): Process: my.edu.utar.sofebos, PID: 7642
>   08-23 12:19:50.449: E/AndroidRuntime(7642): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.edu.utar.sofebos/my.edu.utar.sofebos.Records}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   08-23 12:19:50.449: E/AndroidRuntime(7642):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
>   08-23 12:19:50.449: E/AndroidRuntime(7642):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>   08-23 12:19:50.449: E/AndroidRuntime(7642):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>   08-23 12:19:50.449: E/AndroidRuntime(7642):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>   08-23 12:19:50.449: E/AndroidRuntime(7642):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   08-23 12:19:50.449: E/AndroidRuntime(7642):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   08-23 12:19:50.449: E/AndroidRuntime(7642):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>   08-23 12:19:50.449: E/AndroidRuntime(7642):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   08-23 12:19:50.449: E/AndroidRuntime(7642):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   08-23 12:19:50.449: E/AndroidRuntime(7642):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   08-23 12:19:50.449: E/AndroidRuntime(7642):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>   08-23 12:19:50.449: E/AndroidRuntime(7642):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   08-23 12:19:50.449: E/AndroidRuntime(7642): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   08-23 12:19:50.449: E/AndroidRuntime(7642):     at my.edu.utar.sofebos.Records.onCreate(Records.java:71)
>   08-23 12:19:50.449: E/AndroidRuntime(7642):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>   08-23 12:19:50.449: E/AndroidRuntime(7642):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>   08-23 12:19:50.449: E/AndroidRuntime(7642):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
>   08-23 12:19:50.449: E/AndroidRuntime(7642):     ... 11 more

Comment: you need to debug it here `.onCreate(Records.java:71)` which line is 71

Comment: what should I add in there? Because this activity unable to run.

Comment: please answer my question, **which line is 71**

Comment: `listView.setAdapter(adapter);`
This is line 71

Comment: check your layout file `ListView listView = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.listview);` is returning null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` on the following lines:

```
ListView listView = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.listview);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

1. You will need to check `main.xml` for the id `listview`. Make sure
   it exist.
2. Make sure you are using the right layout `setContentView()`

Comment: @Mike if you comment out this line, do you get an error

Comment: If I comment this line `listView.setAdapter(adapter);` the activity able to run.

Comment: But it still cannot display the listview

Comment: This could also happen if you did not set the right layout `setContentView(R.layout.main);`

Comment: Yes, I copy it from previous activity so forgotten to change it.
After change it solve my problem, thanks much for your help！

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to make a call to the intent that you want?

Here's the code to make a phone intent:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));
    startActivity(callIntent);
```

And in your manifest file add a permission like so:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: I did the intent calling at previous activity, just this activity unable to run.

Comment: ok check your intents and your activity that u declared in your manifest file and then check your list view id and try to define it with another code